# Ошибка при компиляции проекта

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте помогите исправить ошибку

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите полный лог.

Comment: А где его достать?

Comment: Покажите скриншот окна, где фигурирует запись, которую Вы опубликовали в вопросе.

Comment: А Вы случайно не написали в `build.gradle` строчку подключения Annotation Processor в dependencies через `aapt`? Может `apt`?

Comment: Обычно `build-clean` помогает

Comment: не помогло к сожалению...

Comment: Покажите, что написано в Gradle Console (справа снизу кнопка).

Comment: Все я уже починил.